# Only homepage works on angular site after ng build

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm working on an Angular 8 website. The site has multiple pages, www.site.com, www.site.com/foo and www.site.com/bar. When I use ng serve everything works perfectly. However when I run ng build, ng build --prod or ng build --aot the only page that works is the root page. www.mywebsite.com will work but www.mywebsite.com/foo and www.mywebsite.com/bar are a white screen with "File not found."

I have tried building with ng build, ng build --prod and ng build --aot.

I've also tried following directions from this [When running ng build, the index.html does nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51718020/when-running-ng-build-the-index-html-does-nothing)

Here are some routes that are in my app-routing.module.ts

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomepageComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
  { path: 'editorial', component:  EditorialArticleComponent},
  { path: 'article/:id', component: ArticleComponent },
];
```

Update: I am using nginx on an Ubuntu server

Comment: Can you try applying Hashbang mode to your routing and try again on prod ? Here is how you enable hashbang mode : RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }) on your module

Comment: Is this app strictly an Angular app? No .NET Core or anything in it?

Comment: Are you importing the RouterModule in the appModule file?

Comment: This site is strictly Angular. Nothing else is in it. I will try the Hashbang. Also I am importing the RouterModule as well as the Components.

Comment: are you hosting in IIS?

Comment: I'm using an ubuntu server with nginx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this can be done be set the `HashLocationStrategy`, in the root module you need to  set `LocationStrategy` to `HashLocationStrategy`  in the provider list after this change the url will look like this `www.mywebsite.com/#/`

```
{
 providers : [
      { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
 ]
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-locationstrategy-hash)

also check this  [server url rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49074928/issues-with-angular-5-url-rewrite)

Comment: Hey malbarmawi, This works to get rid of the error however on all of the pages /#/foo it shows the home page instead of the /foo page.

Comment: this from the doc  Older browsers send page requests to the server when the location URL changes unless the change occurs after a "#" (called the "hash"). Routers can take advantage of this exception by composing in-application route URLs with hashes. Here's a "hash URL" that routes to the Crisis Center.

Comment: That's really cool. I'm not sure why it's showing the home page though. When I do ng serve it shows the correct page. However as soon as I use ng build it shows the home page no matter what url I use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying your application in IIS

Then you need to make sure below things :

1. URL rewrite is installed
2. Add web.config in your application with URL rewriting

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
   <rewrite>
     <rules>
       <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url=".*" />
         <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
           <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Rewrite" url="/ePortal" />
       </rule>
     </rules>
   </rewrite>
     </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I am using nginx on an Ubuntu 16 server